# Windows 11 periodically freeze 1-2 seconds every 3-10 minutes

Tags: windows, windows-11, freeze

I have a Windows 11 Pro 10.0.22621 Build 22621.2283 on a AMD Ryzen 9 5900X with ProArt X570-CREATOR, 128GB RAM a GPU P2000, only SSD 2TB Evo 970. BIOS was updated to 1301 (latest)

I have done a fresh installation, with latest GPU drivers. Sometimes while writing someting on notepad.exe (only app lauched), all the interface freezes for few seconds the hit key on the keyboard during the freeze keep down and after 1-2 seconds I get multiple hit onnnnnnnnnnnnnn my note.

I checked for resolution but did not find any workaround. Here what I did:

1. Latest GPU driver [checked]
2. Fresh windows installation [checked]
3. dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth [checked]
4. RAM check full [checked]
5. sfc /scannow [checked]
6. No MiniSearchHost process [checked]
7. BIOS update [checked]
8. Paging file recommended 16GB, set to manually 32GB [checked]

Any advice?

Comment: In my experience freezes like this are almost always connected to the storage device

Comment: There is the well documented fTPM issue of course - I know you say "BIOS update [checked]" but since there's no such motherboard as *ProArt X70-CREATOR* can you please add which BIOS version you have - also add information about "the keyboard" since that is what you are having an issue with

Comment: @JaromandaX Indeed I have the ProArt X570 CREATOR WIFI and I had the BIOS 0402, now updated to 1301. Still the issue. Keyboard is a WASD USB and I still have the issue with both the keyboard and the mouse.

Comment: ahhh, X**5**70 - yeah, they exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your problem comes from the Keyboard WASD. Please update the firmware keyboard. Several issues:

https://support.wasdkeyboards.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/1500000861581-Dropped-key-inputs-occasional-lag